# How can I beta test web Perl modules under Apache/mod_perl on production web server?

Tags: perl, apache, testing, mod-perl, perl-module

We have a setup where most code, before being promoted to full production, is deployed in BETA mode - meaning, it runs in full production environment (using production database - usually production data; and production web server). We call that stage BETA testing.

One of the main requirements is that BETA code promotion to production must be a simple "cp" command from beta to production directory - no code/filename changes.

For non-web Perl code, achieving seamless BETA test is quite doable ([see details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474588/how-do-i-use-test-beta-perl-modules-from-test-perl-scripts)):

- Perl programs live in a standard location under production root (`/usr/code/scripts`) with production perl modules living under the same root (`/usr/code/lib/perl`)
- The BETA code has 100% same code paths except under beta root (`/usr/code/beta/`)
- A special module manipulates `@INC` of any script based on whether the script was called from `/usr/code/scripts` or `/usr/code/test/scripts`, to include beta libraries for beta scripts.

This setup works fine up till we need to beta test our web Perl code (the setup is EmbPerl and Apache/mod_perl).

The hang-up is as follows: **if both a production Perl module and BETA Perl module have the same name (e.g. `/usr/code/lib/perl/MyLib1.pm` and `/usr/code/beta/lib/perl/MyLib1.pm`), then mod_perl will only be able to load ONE of these modules into memory** - and there's no way we are aware of for a particular web page to affect which version of the module is currently loaded due to concurrency issues.

Leaving aside the obvious non-programming solution (get a bloody BETA web server) which for political/organizational reasons is not feasible, is there any way we can somehow hack around this problem in either Perl or mod_perl?

I played around with various approaches to unloading Perl modules that `%INC` has listed, but the problem remains that another user might load a beta page at just the right (or rather wrong) moment and have the beta module loaded which will be used for my production page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using mod_perl 2.0 you can use [PerlOptions +Parent](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/config/config.html#C_Parent_) to create a separate Perl interpreter pool for each vhost. It will cost you extra memory, of course, but it will work.

Comment: Brilliant! Don't think Powers That Be would agree to running vhosts on a production web server, but worth a try... I'd still love a solution that doesn't involve vhosts in a very likely case they'll say "no".

Comment: That link uses "PerlSwitches -Mlib=path" and notes: "META: is -Mlib portable? (problems with -Mlib on Darwin/5.6.0?)". Isn't it the same as saying "PerlSwitches -Ipath"?